# Avoiding Timeouts on iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, timeout

I am looking for a good strategy to insert about 2500 id firstName lastName tuples (600KB) from an AJAX call. The timeout happens after the AJAX call completes and while I am storing the data in the localstorage database. The data is in XML format. What I am doing now is converting the XML data into an object by doing a jQuery.each() over the data with this,

```
associateNames[index] = {
   firstName:jQuery(value).find("First").text(),
   lastName:jQuery(value).find("Last").text(),
   id:jQuery(value).find("ID").text()
};
```

Then I pass this object to a function that creates a table and inserts this data. The main part of that function is.

```
    query2.executeSql('CREATE TABLE directory (id unique, fullName)', [],

        // On Success
            function(query, result) {
                jQuery.each(data, function(index, value) {
                    var querySQL = 'INSERT INTO directory (id, fullName) VALUES (' + value.id +
                            ', "'+ encodeURI(value.firstName) + encodeURI(value.lastName) + '")';
                    query.executeSql(querySQL);
                });
            },
```

The iPhone doesn't support web workers. There should be a way to use setInterval() and process pieces of data at a time, but I am getting stuck. Please let me know if you have an idea.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I right in thinking the "data" is an array?  If so you could do something like this:

```
  ...
  //on Success
  function(query, result){
    setTimeout(function(){  //just in case Ajax took a while too..
        var executeBatch = function(startIndex){
            for(var i = startIndex; i < startIndex+50; i++){
                if(i >= data.length) return;
                //do your execute query on data[i]..
            }
            //after short while do the next batch..
            setTimeout(function(){ executeBatch(startIndex+50) }, 50);
        };
        executeBatch(0);
    }, 100);
  }
);
```